# Why is my Indirect formula in Google Sheets not correctly referencing every sheet in a range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of values in Google Sheets, in Column A of a particular sheet. There are an additional 45 sheets where each of the values in Column A might appear once, twice, or not at all. What I want is, for each Column A value, to have a count of the total number of sheets where that value appears at least once.

I'm using the following formula, based on some Googling I did: `=sumproduct(--(countif(indirect("'"&H2:H46&"'!"&"a:a"),A2)>0))`. In column H are the names of sheets I want my formula referencing. It was returning a value of 1, which I didn't understand so I started from just the Indirect part of the formula and tried `=indirect("'"&H2:H46&"'!"&"a:a")`. That should return all the data in Column A from each sheet in my H2:H46 range, or so I thought. It's actually only returning data from the sheet referenced in H2.

I assume this is why the larger formula isn't working. Can someone tell me why my Indirect formula isn't looking at the whole H2:H46 range? And also, how should my larger formula look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=countif(tocol(reduce(,tocol(H2:H46,1),lambda(a,c,{a;unique(indirect("'"&c&"'!A:A"))})),3),A2)
```

- *tested on 3 tabs of minimal dataset*

[image]

Comment: Does this solution give the total number of times the value in Column A appears in the workbook? Or does it give the number of sheets where it appears at least once? Since I'm looking for the latter, which should be a smaller number than the former.

Comment: Updated the formula for latter scenario. In my sample dataset I had `red` in 2 out of 3 sheets